# ¿Como devolver una cadena de texto al haber ejecutado una funcion?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo una funcion que me convierta todas las letras de una palabra en mayúsculas, pero no sé porque me sale error, este es el código

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

char *mayusculas(char texto[]){
int longitud = strlen(texto);
char conversion[longitud] = toupper(texto);
return conversion;
}

void main(){
printf("%s",mayusculas("hola mundo"));
}
```

Y al copilarlo me arroja el siguiente error:

warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
return conversion;

Cómo podría solucionarlo, o como podría hacer para que una funcion me devuelva una cadena

Comment: No, leí ese artículo pero no consigo solución

Answer (score 2):

En la función estas intentando devolver una variable local a esa funcion (conversion) que será destruida al salir de esta, podes solucionarlo declarando 'conversion' como un puntero y asignarle espacio reservado en memoria dinámicamente con `malloc()`, este espacio reservado se mantendrá globalmente y podrás leerlo fuera de la función:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *mayusculas(char texto[]); // prototipo

void main(){
  char* resultado = mayusculas("hola mundo");
  printf("%s", resultado); // imprimimos
  free(resultado); // liberamos la memoria asignada
}

char *mayusculas(char texto[]){
  int longitud = strlen(texto); // obtenemos longitud
  char *conversion = (char *) malloc(longitud + 1); // reservamos memoria dinamicamente, el puntero *conversion apuntara al primer caracter
  for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
    conversion[i] = toupper(texto[i]); // asignamos a cada posicion de la memoria reservada, los caracteres de 'texto' pasados a mayusculas
  }
  conversion[longitud] = '\0'; // las cadenas en C terminan con el caracter '\0', debemos agregarlo para que se reconozca como tal
  return conversion; // devolvemos la cadena
}
```

Comment: No me funciona sale el mismo error

Comment: @KelvinRomero no puede ser, probe el código en muchos compiladores online de C y me funciona en todos [link del codigo](https://onlinegdb.com/sBO8Hk09Y) . Dale click a run en el enlace que te pase.

Comment: Yo estoy usando gcc y me sigue generando el mismo error, no se porque sera

Comment: ¿Por qué declararse la función dentro de la otra? C != C++

Comment: @Mateo funciona en ambos casos pero si, la función puede estar fuera del main() si a eso te refieres

Comment: Veo que confundí C con C++. Es en C++ que no se puede hacer eso.

Answer (score 0):

- La función [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) recibe un entero, no una cadena de caracteres.
- Las variables locales dejan de existir al salir de la función. No es útil devolver un puntero a una variable local.

Puedes reservar memoria dentro de la función y devolver un puntero a ella. El problema es que le dejas la responsabilidad de liberarla a la función que la llame.

Una mejor forma es recibir un puntero al lugar donde la función que la llamó crea adecuado guardar la información.

Modificando la cadena que recibes, el código sería así:

```
void mayusculas(char* texto){
    int longitud = strlen(texto);
    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++){
        texto[i] = toupper(texto[i]);
    }
}
```

Sin modificar la cadena original:

```
void mayusculas(const char* texto, char * destino, int tamanoDestino){
    int longitud = strlen(texto);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < longitud && i < tamanoDestino - 1; i++){
        destino[i] = toupper(texto[i]);
    }
    destino[i] = 0;
}
```

En este caso, el main se vería así:

```
int main(){
    char convertido[100] = "";
    mayusculas("texto", convertido, 100);
    printf(convertido);
}
```

---

Por cierto, cuando se trate de punteros, acostumbra a marcar los parámetros como constantes si la función no los va a alterar.